Как различить соединительный и присоединительный союз И?
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Различение соединительного и присоединительного союза И — одна из важных проблем при выборе знаков препинания. Недостаточно просто назвать значение союза присоединительным, но надо провести грамматический анализ предложения.
Дело в том, что присоединительное значение союза И надо отличить от соединительного.

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
ТЕОРИЯ
Присоединительными называются члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительную информацию. В то же время присоединительные члены  неоднородны по семантике и грамматике. В общем случае к ним относят как присоединительные члены со значением дополнительного пояснения, уточнения, включения и т. д., образующие сочинительный ряд, так и просто обособленные члены в добавочном сообщении (которые  в такой ряд не входят).
Почему это важно при выборе знаков? Дело в том, что следует различать однородную и присоединительную связь для ряда (разные знаки), в то время как присоединительные члены, не входящие в ряд, обособляются всегда.
СОЮЗ И: соединительный или присоединительный
Вдруг рванул ветер, И с такой силой, что выхватил у него узелок. Только обособление.
Она вслух читала романы, И была виновата во всех ошибках автора. Возможны варианты (однородные или присоединительные отношения).
ПРАКТИКА

Был подписан ряд важных соглашений в различных сферах, и прежде всего в сфере торговли.

Здесь два обстоятельства образуют ряд, но второе обстоятельство включено в первое, то есть уже названо. Поэтому требуется обязательное обособление. Падежная форма прежде всего использована в значении присоединительного союза  с нужной семантикой. Это более частотный вариант.

Осознанность стала очень популярной практикой в лечебных центрах, компаниях, учебных аудиториях, мастерских и прежде всего в исследовательских лабораториях по всему миру. Марат Рашитович Шаехов, Школа ценностей, 2022

В этом предложении сочинительный ряд, однородные отношения; падежная форма прежде всего дифференцирует значение последнего однородного члена, подчеркивая его важность. Здесь обособление будет некорректным.
